# error when converting linq lambda query to list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

i am trying to query data using linq, i am joining two tables where id == to id of the second table. i am getting an exception error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<--db table here-->`'.

```
var qry = context.Projects
                .Join(context.Members, p => p.ID, m => m.ID, (p, m) => new { p, m })
                .Where(u => u.m.ID == memId)
                .Select(b => new  { 
                     b.p.ProjName,
                     b.p.ProjDesc,
                     b.p.ProjectType, 
                     b.p.Tags
                });
 return qry.ToList();
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.  The return type of your method doesn't match what you're actually returning.  They need to match.  Also that's not an exception, it's a compile time error.  Big difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to return a list of *anonymous type* from your method but the return type is probably something like `List<SomeType>`.

So instead of creating anonymous objects you need to create objects of your type.

```
.Select(b => new  SomeType { 
                 // set properties here
            });
```